# Adding a button to the CMS in SilverStripe

Tags: button, content-management-system, silverstripe

How do I add a button to the backend of the CMS that fires an action? I can display the button where I want using:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldsToTab("Root.ButtonTest", array(
            FormAction::create('doAction', 'Action button')
        )
    );

    return $fields;
}

public function doAction() 
{
   //Do something
}
```

However the button added does nothing when clicked.

I've seen one example of how to put a button on the main action bar (next to save/publish) but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Looking at the only [page of documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20140817055240/http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/trunk/howto/extend-cms-interface) I can find, do I need to do something within:

```
public function getCMSActions()
{
    $actions = parent::getCMSActions();
    //Something here?
}
```

It isn't very clear how to create the action that the button calls.

Comment: what do you want the button to 'do'? would it be an option to render a checkbox and react to it in the 'onBeforeWrite' hook?

Comment: Not really, the button will be sending a request to a third party service, checking the response and displaying it to the user. Ideally without reloading the page. Might just be easier to use a bit of js on a blur event or something.

Comment: The document manager system module does this, but I don't really know enough about SS yet to reverse engineer how they have done it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to extend/decorate `LeftAndMain` with your own extension and the action you want to call. Here's an example:

```
<?php
class MyExtension extends LeftAndMainExtension
{
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'doAction'  
    );

    public function doAction($data, $form){
        $className = $this->owner->stat('tree_class');
        $SQL_id = Convert::raw2sql($data['ID']);

        $record = DataObject::get_by_id($className, $SQL_id);

        if(!$record || !$record->ID){
            throw new SS_HTTPResponse_Exception(
                "Bad record ID #" . (int)$data['ID'], 404);
        }

        // at this point you have a $record, 
        // which is your page you can work with!

        // this generates a message that will show up in the CMS
        $this->owner->response->addHeader(
            'X-Status',
            rawurlencode('Success message!') 
        );

        return $this->owner->getResponseNegotiator()
               ->respond($this->owner->request);
    }
}
```

Once you have written an extension like this, you'll have to apply it to `LeftAndMain` by adding the following to your `mysite/_config/config.yml`:

```
LeftAndMain:
  extensions:
    - MyExtension
```

That's it. Your `doAction` button should now actually do something!

Comment: Makes perfect sense - Thanks!

Comment: `doAction` does not need to be in `$allowed_actions`, it is called from `Form->httpSubmission`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is helpful, but here's how you can add action-buttons to a ModelAdmin.
(does reload the page)

...in the admin class:

```
public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null)
{
    $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);
    $form
        ->Fields()
        ->fieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass))
        ->getConfig()
        ->getComponentByType('GridFieldDetailForm')
        ->setItemRequestClass('MyGridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest');

    return $form;
}
```

MyGridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest.php

```
class MyGridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest extends GridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest
{
    function ItemEditForm()
    {
        $form = parent::ItemEditForm();
        $formActions = $form->Actions();

        $button = FormAction::create('myAction');
        $button->setTitle('button label');
        $button->addExtraClass('ss-ui-action-constructive');
        $formActions->push($button);


        $form->setActions($formActions);
        return $form;
    }

    public function myAction(){ //do things } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond but it doesn't really give me a clear answer. Unfortunately this is all people seem to want to do and Google is covered in examples for this situation but not others.

Comment: if you mean the "Add Documents" button in the DMS module, you might want to take look at this: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/cms-architecture#pjax-partial-template-replacement-through-ajax (i think that what it used there...)